# Different background image for different posts - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

Is there a way for me to add a separate background image for a specific post on my rails app?

In my rails app I have different mixtapes, and I would like to add a custom background image for some of the mixtapes "show" view (not for every mixtape though).

I would upload the images myself.

Is there a gem or a tutorial that shows me how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your specification is incomplete. Where will the images come from? Will users (or you) upload them, or will there be a fixed number of images to choose from?

Comment: I would upload the images myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways how to do it, and the easiest one (in my opinion) is to define a CSS selector that is responsible for that and to set it from your Rails application.

Something like the following pseudo-code:

```
%div{:class => @post.bg_class}
```

Then your `application.css` file should include something like:

```
div.img1 {
    background-image:url(img1.gif);
}
div.img2 {
    ...
}
```

Or you could style your div directly with the necessary style (not tested this one):

```
%div{:style => "background-image: #{@post.bg_image};"}
```

But the difficult part is to find for each different post a background image ...